# Saving and loading Textcolor and TypeFace using SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

The APP project I am working on acts as a personal schedule where you can write in what your schedule for the next day looks like, save it and on app creation all the text you originally input will still be there. I originally got the save and load function working using Shared Preferences but now I want to add a highlighter option to the app that changes the text in specific editTexts to be Bold and the color Red.

I have tried using a boolean sharedPref variable as a way of telling what the EditText color and typeface should be but I'm sure I am coding it wrong. Here is the code:

```
  EditText et0;
  Button hb0, b1, b2;
public static final String SHARED_PREFS = "sharedPrefs";
public static final String SIX_AM = "sixAM";
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final MediaPlayer saveMP = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.save);
    final MediaPlayer aNewDayMP = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.anewday);

    // Each declared EditText variable in the code is then assigned an EditText from the xml.
    et0 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.slot0);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.clearButton);
    hB0=(Button)findViewById(R.id.highLighter0);

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            saveMP.start();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(SIX_AM, et0.getText().toString());

            editor.commit();

            // Declaring a toast for the user to see they have saved their own data.
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

   b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            aNewDayMP.start();
            et0.setText("");
        }
    });

   hB0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           if (et0.getCurrentTextColor()==Color.BLACK) {
               et0.setTextColor(Color.RED);
               et0.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
               hBB0 = TRUE;

            } else {
                et0.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                et0.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                hBB0 = FALSE;

            }


        }
    });

    loadData();

}
// The loadData method
public void loadData(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    et0.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(SIX_AM, ""));


Please note I am a complete amateur and did my best to parse away lines of code that weren't important to the question. If anyone can help or has a recommendation on a better way to do this, please let me know, cheers.
```

Comment: have you tried using appyl instead of commit ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the trouble lies in the fact that you initialize sharedPreferences twice, first in onCreate() as field (class attribute) and second in loadData as local variable. I think that if you delete the initialization in loadData and simply use the field initialized in onCreate it should read the stored value.